# can't debug AWS API gateway with velocity template integrating with dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, velocity

I am testing an API gateway in AWS instance with one compulsory query string parameter (named 'tag') and 3 other non-compulsory query string parameters. The API is set to be linked to AWS service with an integration request which transforms API request with Apache Velocity Template before sending it to dynamoDB. tha template is the following:

```html
#set($tag = $input.params('tag'))
#set($wifi = $input.params('wifi'))
#if($wifi)
    #set($wifiBool = $wifi=='true' ? true : false)
#end
#set($exclusiveStartKey = $input.params('exclusive_start_key'))
#set($limit = $input.params('limit'))
#if($limit)
    #set($limitInt = $tool.parseInt($limit))
#end

#set($logMessage = "tag: $tag, wifiBool: $wifiBool, exclusiveStartKey: $exclusiveStartKey, limitInt: $limitInt")
$logMessage


{
    "TableName":"places",
    "KeyConditionExpression":"tag=:tag",
    #if($wifi)
    "FilterExpression": "wifi=:wifi",
    #end
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":tag":{
            "S":$tag
        } #if($wifi),
        ":wifi":{
            "BOOL":$wifiBool
        }
        #end
        
    } #if($exclusiveStartKey),
    "ExclusiveStartKey": $exclusiveStartKey,
    #end #if($limit),
    "Limit": $limitInt,
    #end
    
}
```

its purpose is to to query a dynamoDB table based on several parameters which are passed as query strings; the only one compulsory is 'tag' which is also the partition key of the dynamodb table. I set the role for the API Gateway as with the following policies:

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:PartiQLSelect",
                "dynamodb:PartiQLUpdate",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PartiQLInsert",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:PartiQLDelete"
            ],
            "Resource": "my_table_arn"
        }
    ]
}
```

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

the HTTP method used to interact with dynamoDB (the one which API gateway uses under the hood) is POST while the method which I am setting (the one used to make requests directly to API gateway) is a GET. The logs obtained when I test the API with a request with query parameter 'tag=office' are the following:

```html
Execution log for request 211c0796-d739-491f-9a13-a144a524cef0
Sat Sep 02 18:04:07 UTC 2023 : Starting execution for request: 211c0796-d739-491f-9a13-a144a524cef0
Sat Sep 02 18:04:07 UTC 2023 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /places
Sat Sep 02 18:04:07 UTC 2023 : Method request path: {}
Sat Sep 02 18:04:07 UTC 2023 : Method request query string: {tag=office}
Sat Sep 02 18:04:07 UTC 2023 : Method request headers: {}
Sat Sep 02 18:04:07 UTC 2023 : Method request body before transformations: 
Sat Sep 02 18:04:07 UTC 2023 : Request validation succeeded for content type application/json
Sat Sep 02 18:04:07 UTC 2023 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request
Sat Sep 02 18:04:07 UTC 2023 : Method completed with status: 500
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, if someone could help I would be really grateful